# Adding Button on top of Table View - Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I want to know how to add a UIRect Button on top of a table view using Interface Builder, like the one in this image:

[image]

It's a + (plus) button on top of a table view.

How to do this in Interface Builder? I can not drag the button onto the Table View. It can only placed below the table view..

Or it must be done only in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plus button shown in image can be done with coding.

How to.

Add pulse button (`UIButton`) as  a subview to the superview of table view.(means your table view and the pulse will be sibling).

Give it the proper rect so that it could be seen just above to tabs,

Comment: Thanks.. So there is no way using the Interface Builder for this?

Comment: But dude,i am not talking abt Interface Builder, As i mentoined in post through "coding" ...., if you need sample code, i can provide u

Comment: Of course it can be done by code.. I'm just curious why I can't do it with Interface Builder.. That's my reasoning for asking.. But thanks anyway for your answer..